# Stopping an update in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates

Is there any way to stop an update once it has started? There appears to be a cancel button but whenever I have updated ubuntu thus far it has always been greyed out. Today I accidentally agreed to an update on ubuntu. This update is still crawling along some 3 hours later. Is there any way to stop it without totalling the system?

(Incidentally I have yet to see any function these updates actually serve - I still had to manually sort of shellshock etc. I would appreciate advice from more experienced users on how often updates should be performed and how important they actually are.)

Comment: Some questions:

 1. What is slow?  The download or the update itself?
 2. What is your hardware like? (CPU/mem/disk)
 3. Are you doing updates on shutdown or using the UI?
 4. Automatic or manual?

Comment: Oh no! Not you again!  ;)
(Just noticed the name now...)

Comment: Yeah, me again. 

OK, so this was one of these automated update messages - I accidentally agreed to the update. I think the update itself was slow - no noticeable problems with internet speed when I thought to check if that was the problem. I was using the UI. I'm running this one in virtual box as a guest with Windows 8 as the host. The virtual machine has 1GB of RAM and a 30GB hard drive. The update did eventually complete but it would still be of value to be able to stop it in the future.

Comment: Some recommendations:
;) I'm currently installing 3 old machines with the same RAM as yours but I'm using Lubuntu on those... On 2GB machines with a decent processor and disk I use vanilla Ubuntu, otherwise Lubuntu again and on anything higher Ubuntu latest and greatest. In a perfect world with unlimited budgets: give Ubuntu its own machines.  In your case, please don't starve Ubuntu from much needed RAM:  3GB if you can spare it and it'll be much faster already! (and Windows as a host system which uses swap very differently from *nix is also not an ideal situation)  Sorry!

Comment: I can't spare 3GB. It's highly reccommended you don't exceed half of the memory allowance of your computer. I actually told you wrong it has 2GB of RAM. The whole computer only has 5.71GB of useable RAM so I'm already near the upper limit.

Comment: No, you told me it was 1GB... LUbuntu IMHO.  From 2GB and up I start using vanilla Ubuntu with some bells and whistles. more then that: all the bells and whistles!  It's a VM anyway.  If you have time, try LUbuntu... It has a start button in the lower left corner of the screen!  ;) (Grinning, ducking and running...)

Comment: Yeah as I say I told you wrong in the first instance. I'm not sure if LUbuntu is available on virtual box but maybe at some point when I have time and wwant to dual boot rather than simultaneously using Windows and Linux I could give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First the answer to the questions:**

*Is there a way to stop the upgrade process?*

Depending on how the upgrade process was started, yes there is...

- If you do the upgrade process using `sudo apt-get upgrade`, **YES:** just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> at any time and it stops.
- If you do the upgrades during a shutdown: I finally had the time to test the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during shutdown and the same applies:  **YES:** it just stops.
- If you do the upgrade using the GUI:  **NO:** And definitely not so as the cancel button is always greyed out once you start.

*How important are updates?*
As usual, it's a balance between security and availability:

- If you need a highly secure system: check daily; security updates: download and install automatically; other updates: display immediately; install immediately when you see them; activate updates on shutdown.
- If you need a highly available system: check every fortnight; download automatically; display every fortnight; Install when you can; activate updates on shutdown.
- A "secure" balance: Check daily; security updates: download and install automatically; other updates: display weekly; install them when you see them, activate updates on shutdown.
- An "available" balance: Check daily; security updates: download and install automatically; other updates: display weekly; install them when you see them, activate updates on shutdown.

In Ubuntu, updates rarely need a reboot, so the above is a good rule-of-thumb, but *every situation is different* and needs to be put into context.  If you have Ubuntu machines running in a laboratory environment where you produce vaccines and need a *highly available and highly secure* system, take the "highly secure" option, but schedule it every night at midnight when the production is stopped because the incubators are being sterilised anyway...

### :-)